# Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 Upgrade: Could not download the upgrades

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I'm trying to upgrade my Desktop Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.  I'm logged in using the Gnome desktop.  I get the following error, every time:

```
Could not download the upgrades
The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-mahjongg/gnome-mahjongg_3.18.0-1_amd64.deb Size mismatch
```

There is nothing wrong with my Internet connection.  I've also tried, as suggested by answers, to other similar questions:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

(I think the Distribution Upgrade app does an update before attempting to upgrade)

I've also tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

(Just in case)

Please advise what diagnostics I can run next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-mahjongg
```

Really! A desktop game prevented the upgrade o.O

The upgrade was successful after removing the game.

Comment: This could be a bug. I advice to submit a new bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-mahjongg/+bugs?field.status:list=NEW)